# How to Insert new Record into Table if the Record is not Present in the Table in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I want to insert a new record if the record is not present in the table

For that I am using below query in Teradata

```
 INSERT INTO sample(id, name) VALUES('12','rao')
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM sample WHERE id = '12');
```

When I execute the above query I am getting below error.

```
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
 
Failure 3706 Syntax error: expected something between ')' and the 'WHERE' keyword.
```

Can anyone help with the above issue. It will be very helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` as follows:

```
INSERT INTO sample(id,name)
 select '12','rao'
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM sample WHERE id = '12');
```

You can also create the `primary`/`unique` key on `id` column to avoid inserting duplicate data in `id` column.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise writing the query as:

```
INSERT INTO sample (id, name)
   SELECT id, name
   FROM (SELECT 12 as id, 'rao' as name) x
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sample s WHERE s.id = x.id);
```

This means that you do not need to repeat the constant value -- such repetition can be a cause of errors in queries.  Note that I removed the single quotes.  `id` looks like a number so treat it as a number.

The uniqueness of `id`s is usually handled using a unique constraint or index:

```
alter table sample add constraint unq_sample_id unique (id);
```

This makes sure that the *database* ensures uniqueness.  Your approach can fail if two `insert`s are run at the same time with the same id.  An attempt to insert a duplicates returns an error (which the `exists` can then avoid).

In practice, `id` columns are usually generated automatically by the database.  So the `create table` statement would look more like:

```
id integer generated by default as identity
```

And the insert would look like:

```
insert into sample (name)
    values (name);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is the Primary Index of the table you can use `MERGE`:

```
merge into sample as tgt 
using VALUES('12','rao') as src (id, name)
on src.id = tgt.id
when not matched
then insert (src.id,src.name)
```